# why this is correct in mvvm pattern and the messageBox isnt? I don't see the difference (MVVM Light)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, messagebox

I found a small example that uses MVVM Light to show a message to the user. How it uses MVVM Light, I guess, is that it respects the MVVM pattern.

The view code behind:

```
namespace DialogosPruebas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
                this,
                msg =>
                {
                    var result = MessageBox.Show(
                        msg.Content,
                        msg.Caption,
                        msg.Button);

                    // Send callback
                    msg.ProcessCallback(result);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And the `ViewModel` is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

namespace DialogosPruebas.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// Use the <strong>mvvminpc</strong> snippet to add bindable properties to this ViewModel.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// You can also use Blend to data bind with the tool's support.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private const string Login = "abcd1234";

        public RelayCommand<string> CheckLoginCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="Message" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string MessagePropertyName = "Message";

        private string _message = "Login";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Message property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_message == value)
                {
                    return;
                }    
                _message = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(MessagePropertyName);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CheckLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(CheckLogin);
        }

        private void CheckLogin(string text)
        {
            if (text == Login)
            {
                var message = new DialogMessage("Login confirmed, do you want to continue", DialogMessageCallback)
                {
                    Button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                    Caption = "Continue?"
                };
                Messenger.Default.Send(message);
            }
        }

        private void DialogMessageCallback(MessageBoxResult result)
        {
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                Message = "Continue";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Stop";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The AXML:

```
<Window x:Class="DialogosPruebas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
        <TextBlock FontSize="36"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="Purple"
            Text="{Binding Message}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10" />

        <TextBox x:Name="LoginTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" FontSize="21.333" Text="Enter login">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CheckLoginCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=LoginTextBox}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="(Enter abcd1234 to trigger the message)" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="16" Foreground="White"/>

    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Well, my doubt is, in the code behind the view we use `MessageBox` and the `ViewModel` has this code:

```
var message = new DialogMessage("Login confirmed, do you want to continue", DialogMessageCallback)
                {
                    Button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                    Caption = "Continue?"
                };

                Messenger.Default.Send(message);
```

This sends a request to the view, to the code behind, that then uses `MessageBox`.

Why is this better than this solution, which uses `MessageBox` in the `ViewModel` directly, like this:

```
private void CheckLogin(string text)
        {
            if (text == Login)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login correct");
            }
        }
```

?

What is the difference? In both cases I use `MessageBox` and I have to wait for the user's response.

I have read that to use `MessageBox` in the `viewModel` is not a good idea, but I don't see what the difference is in this case.

Comment: This is essentially a better solution because you do not want the ViewModel to know anything about the UI.. By using a messaging system, the View is able to show the MessageBox w/out coupling it directly to the ViewModel (which should not contain any UI controls)

Comment: MVVM is a great way to overcomplicate the most trivial of tasks. :)

Comment: @Gigi that's not true. MVVM is a solution to problems you might or might not have. See my answer. I have created my own multi-platform framework and I found myself forced to abstract away a lot of seemingly "simple" and "trivial" things, due to the platform-independent nature. Anything that's "trivial" in platform "A" might not be supported or have a completely different approach in platform "B".

Comment: @HighCore I am pretty familiar with MVVM :) It's good in many scenarios, but in many other cases it's an overengineered approach. If you are doing platform-independent stuff then you do need abstraction. But for many simpler applications, the abstraction itself tends to get in the way. Case in point is stuff like this where the view needs to update conditionally based on the VM - message boxes, animations, etc - these are not as easy to do in MVVM as they are without it.

Comment: Write a unit test that covers the method, then come back and answer your question for yourself.

Comment: You might find https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction interesting.  It's for MvvmCross but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two reasons why this approach might be desirable:

**1 - Your ViewModels need to be Unit Tested.**

raising modal dialogs such as a `MessageBox` leads to all sorts of problems in Unit Tests. The decoupled `Messenger` approach is safe because in a Unit Test, either no one is listening to the messages, or there is a mocked listener that just returns "Yes" for all user-facing prompts.

**2 - Your ViewModels are supposed to be reused on other platforms.**

Don't worry about this too much if you're targeting Windows (WPF) only.

The main concern that leads to complete separation from UI is if you will reuse your ViewModels in other platforms.

For example, there's no `MessageBox.Show()` in Android, therefore, if you intend to reuse your ViewModel's "Application Logic" there you will need to abstract that code away and provide platform-specific code on each case.

If none of these are important for you, then IMO it's perfectly fine to raise MessageBoxes in your ViewModels, as well as other View-specific issues (such as Window closing) which might be overly complex given the abstractions required by MVVM, for no gain.

Comment: I was thinking on this solution. A wrapper, a dll that is an interface with an enum to set the type of messageBox, so the view model does not need to use MessageBoxButton because this does not exists on silverlight. And another dll project that implement this interface. The class that implements the interface is not MVVM, only use messageBox. That's a good solution? The view model can execute unit test and don't know the way that the class show the dialog.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía seems fine. I have implemented a similar solution. Keep in mind that all your platform agnostic code might live in PCLs (Portable Class Libraries).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that by sending a message (DialogMessage) your ViewModel is asking the View to show a message. How the message is actually displayed depends on the View. In this case the View will show a simple MessageBox but it could use a UserControl to show a custom dialog.

Using a message the ViewModel doesn't need to know how the message will be displayed so it's still decoupled from the View.